# I get these errors when I use the ```npm run dev``` command

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack

```
Error: Cannot find module 'This is the Folder path \bin\webpack.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47* {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ dev: `webpack serve --config ./bundler/webpack.dev.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\21697\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-09-20T20_54_58_070Z-debug.log
PS C:This is the Folder path>
```

PS: I did delete both the package-lock & node_modules and reinstalled npm using `npm install`
but the problem still exists, I also tried reinstalling node js, same thing

Answer (score 0):

`Error: Cannot find module 'This is the Folder path \bin\webpack.js'`

It's looking for a module with name/path `'This is the Folder path \bin\webpack.js'`. That doesn't look like a valid module name/path.

Looks like you added some debug text somewhere you shouldn't have.

Hard to come up with other explanations since you did not post any of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it by reinstalling both node js & npm and instlalling chokidar 3 using the command  `npm i chokidar@3.0.0` it turns out that the previous version does not support node js 14+